# Interesting Behavior with Dictionary and ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I had a dictionary in the python REPL: `d ={"abc": 1, "def":2}`. I opened a file from the REPL (`with open("file","w") as f:`) and wrote the dictionary to the file using `f.write(str(d))`.

For reference, `file` then has the following contents: `"{'abc': 1, 'def': 2}"`

I then ran a script:

```
with open("file","r") as g:
    text = g.readlines()[0].rstrip('\n')
    print [text], type(text)
    evaldic = literal_eval(text)
    print [evaldic],type(evaldic)
    evaldic2 = literal_eval(evaldic)
    print [evaldic2],type(evaldic)
```

which gave the following output:

```
['"{\'abc\': 1, \'def\': 2}"'] <type 'str'>
["{'abc': 1, 'def': 2}"] <type 'str'>
[{'abc': 1, 'def': 2}] <type 'dict'>
```

Which suggests that the first pass of `literal_eval` removes the slashed formatting and evaluated the input string... to be a string? And only the second pass of `literal_eval` evaluated the string to be a dictionary?

Why? What's going on here? Why does `literal_eval` need to evaluate the input string to be a string, i.e. remove formatting, first? Why do I need to do two evaluation passes?

Comment: There's no way your file will contain those double quotes if you used `str(d)`.

Comment: @Newb: did you at any point use `str = repr`? Because Ashwini is correct, your output cannot be reproduced using the built-in `str()` call.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, you were right. I must have done something else along the way... Martijn, I did not use `repr` at any point (unless implicitly, without me knowing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encoded your data *twice* with `repr()`:

```
>>> d = {'abc': 1, 'def': 2}
>>> repr(d)
"{'abc': 1, 'def': 2}"
>>> repr(repr(d))
'"{\'abc\': 1, \'def\': 2}"'
```

It is the latter version you wrote to the file; it is a string containing a representation of a Python string, which in turn is a representation of a Python dictionary.

Note that the code in your question doesn't produce your problem:

```
>>> import ast
>>> d = {'abc': 1, 'def': 2}
>>> with open("file","w") as f: f.write(str(d))
... 
>>> with open("file","r") as f: ast.literal_eval(f.read())
... 
{'abc': 1, 'def': 2}
>>> type(_)
<type 'dict'>
```

Only when using `repr()` when writing a string representation of a dictionary to the file would you produce the output you see when reading the file again. Even `str(str(d))` doesn't produce it, for example.

Comment: Ah! I see. How can I avoid writing double representations?

Comment: @Newb: you haven't shown us how you produced the file; the code you posted in your question doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the file. Something must have happened somewhere along the way. I'll let you know if I figure out what that was.